# Extract PhysicalFace as 2D mesh in fipy

Tags: mesh, fipy

I created a mesh with Gmsh (a surface with a hole and then extruded it). Now I would like to plot the model in individual slices after a simulation with e.g. the MatplotlibViewer (Mayavi does not work on both my computers). I had hoped that it would be possible to define a new net using mesh.physicalFaces, but if that is possible, I have not figured it out yet. My second attempt was to apply the mesh again with Gmsh up to the Extrude command. But the mesh corresponds not to that of the 3D version. Can somebody give me a clue on this? Also like just another approach to representation.

I am working on Win10, Fipy 3.1.3, Python 3.6

```py
import numpy as np
from fipy import *
#%%
def func_mesh():
    mesh = Gmsh3D('''
    Geometry.OCCAutoFix = 0;
    SetFactory("OpenCASCADE");

    x = 1.;
    bseg = 0.08;
    bs= bseg*x;
    ls = 2.1; 
    cl = 0.01;
    radius = 0.006;

    // Exterior (bounding box) of mesh
    Point(1) = {0, 0, 0, cl};
    Point(2) = {0, bs, 0, cl};
    Point(4) = { bs,  0, 0, cl};
    Point(3) = {bs,  bs, 0, cl};
    Line(1) = {1, 2};
    Line(2) = {2, 3};
    Line(3) = {3, 4};
    Line(4) = {4, 1};
    Line Loop (21) = {1,2,3,4};


    //Circle
    Point(5) = {bseg/2 - radius, bseg/2, 0, cl};
    Point(6) = {bseg/2, bseg/2 + radius, 0, cl};
    Point(7) = { bseg/2 + radius, bseg/2, 0, cl};
    Point(8) = {bseg/2, bseg/2 - radius, 0, cl};
    Point(9) =  {bseg/2, bseg/2, 0, cl};

    Circle(10) = {5,9,6};
    Circle(11) = {6,9,7};
    Circle(12) = {7,9,8};
    Circle(13) = {8,9,5};
    Line Loop(22) = {10,11,12,13};
    Plane Surface(40) = {22}; //cycl

    Plane Surface(15) = {21, 22}; //Surface with a hole


    id[] = Extrude {0, 0, ls} {Surface{15}; Layers{210}; Recombine;};

    Surface Loop(2) = {46, 45, 48, 47, 49, 41, 44, 43, 42, 15};

    Physical Volume("Vol") = {id[]};

    Physical Surface("surf_ges") = {41, 42, 43, 44, 49, 47, 45, 48, 46, 15};

    Physical Surface("HX") = {45, 46, 48, 47};

    Physical Surface("Extr") = {15};

    ''')
    return mesh

    mesh = func_mesh()

    x,y,z = mesh.cellCenters 
    X,Y,Z = mesh.faceCenters

    tS = CellVariable(name="storage", 
                      mesh=mesh, 
                      value=367., 
                      hasOld=True)

submesh = mesh.physicalFaces['Extr']
xsub, ysub = submesh.cellCenters
tSslice = CellVariable(name = 'tSsclice',
                 mesh = submesh,
                 value = tS[z== z[0]])
viewer = MatplotlibViewer(vars = tSslice)
```

The error message for this attemp is: AttributeError: 'binOp' object has no attribute 'cellCenters'.
If I redefine the mesh only until the extrude order I get:
"ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)"  because of the shape of tSslice.
I am grateful for any help

Answer (score 2):

`submesh` is not a `Mesh`; it's a mask identifying which faces of `mesh` are included in the surface `Extr`.

FiPy has no facility for extracting a mesh out of another mesh. It should be feasible to create a `Mesh2D` using the `submesh` mask, `mesh.vertexCoords`, and `mesh.faceVertexIDs`, but it's not trivial.

In theory, you could invoke `Gmsh2D` with everything up to `Plane Surface(15) = {21, 22}; //Surface with a hole`, but I find that doesn't generate the same number of elements as your 3D slice at `z == z[0]`.

Ahah, I see the issue. I thought the `Extrude` operation resulted in prismatic cells, but it does not. The cells are tetrahedral. Since the cells of `mesh` do not all have the same tetrahedral geometry, the cells that have their bases on `Extr` are not all guaranteed to have their centers at `z == z[0]`. A better way is to use FiPy's `CellVariable` interpolation to extract the values of `tS` at the coordinates of `tSslice`:

```py
from fipy import *

geo = '''
Geometry.OCCAutoFix = 0;
SetFactory("OpenCASCADE");

x = 1.;
bseg = 0.08;
bs= bseg*x;
ls = 2.1; 
cl = 0.01;
radius = 0.006;

// Exterior (bounding box) of mesh
Point(1) = {0, 0, 0, cl};
Point(2) = {0, bs, 0, cl};
Point(4) = { bs,  0, 0, cl};
Point(3) = {bs,  bs, 0, cl};
Line(1) = {1, 2};
Line(2) = {2, 3};
Line(3) = {3, 4};
Line(4) = {4, 1};
Line Loop (21) = {1,2,3,4};


//Circle
Point(5) = {bseg/2 - radius, bseg/2, 0, cl};
Point(6) = {bseg/2, bseg/2 + radius, 0, cl};
Point(7) = { bseg/2 + radius, bseg/2, 0, cl};
Point(8) = {bseg/2, bseg/2 - radius, 0, cl};
Point(9) =  {bseg/2, bseg/2, 0, cl};

Circle(10) = {5,9,6};
Circle(11) = {6,9,7};
Circle(12) = {7,9,8};
Circle(13) = {8,9,5};
Line Loop(22) = {10,11,12,13};
Plane Surface(40) = {22}; //cycl

Plane Surface(15) = {21, 22}; //Surface with a hole


id[] = Extrude {0, 0, ls} {Surface{15}; Layers{210}; Recombine;};

Surface Loop(2) = {46, 45, 48, 47, 49, 41, 44, 43, 42, 15};

Physical Volume("Vol") = {id[]};

Physical Surface("Extr") = {15};
'''

mesh = Gmsh3D(geo + '''
Physical Surface("surf_ges") = {41, 42, 43, 44, 49, 47, 45, 48, 46, 15};

Physical Surface("HX") = {45, 46, 48, 47};
'''
)
submesh = Gmsh2D(geo)

x,y,z = mesh.cellCenters 
X,Y = submesh.cellCenters[..., submesh.physicalCells['Extr']]
Z = numerix.ones(X.shape) * z[0]

tS = CellVariable(name="storage", 
                  mesh=mesh, 
                  value=mesh.x * mesh.y * mesh.z, 
                  hasOld=True)

tSslice = CellVariable(name = 'tSsclice',
                 mesh = submesh)

# interpolate values of tS at positions of tSslice
tSslice[..., submesh.physicalCells['Extr']] = tS(numerix.vstack([X, Y, Z]))

viewer = MatplotlibViewer(vars = tSslice)
```

Here, I use the same `.geo` script to define both `mesh` and `submesh`. I add the `surf_ges` and `HX` physical surfaces only to the definition of `mesh`, because otherwise all of these faces will be imported into `submesh` as well, although with an effective `z` value of 0, so they obscure the faces you're interested in.

Frankly, I think a better way to achieve a slice through 3D data like this is to use either a customized [MayaviClient](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/fipy/generated/fipy.viewers.mayaviViewer.html#module-fipy.viewers.mayaviViewer.mayaviClient) (see the [Cahn-Hilliard sphere](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/examples/cahnHilliard/generated/examples.cahnHilliard.sphere.html) and [`sphereDaemon.py`](https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/blob/master/examples/cahnHilliard/sphereDaemon.py) for an example) or export with a [VTKViewer](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/fipy/generated/fipy.viewers.vtkViewer.html#module-fipy.viewers.vtkViewer.vtkViewer) and then render your data slices with a tool like [ParaView](https://www.paraview.org/), [VisIt](https://wci.llnl.gov/simulation/computer-codes/visit/), or [Mayavi](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/).